# Creating an Android app to let the user freeze frames and edit a video

Tags: android-studio, video-editing

I am new to Android Studio, and I am trying to develop an app that would let a user to open a video in their device and then let the user edit that video in a way that he can pause/freeze the video frames at any point of time, add a transparent background and some text to the video and save.

Once the saved video is played, the added background and text will be displayed over the video to the set period of time while the video frame is frozen.

I've read about video codecs that can be used to support these types of requirements.

I am looking for a point to begin developing this app, and couldn't find a place to start. If anyone can guide me on how to start with such a project I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!